# Git merge after a squash

Tags: git

I have two repositories A and B. I wanted to merge A into B without the whole history, so I did:

```
git pull --squash A_URL master
```

which seemed to work. B no has an Initial commit and a merge commit.
I continued working on A and then tried to merge it into B again but this time keeping the history.

```
git pull A_URL master
```

The problem is all the history of A now shows in B even the commits that were initially squashed. Is there a fix for this? 
Basically I only want to get the more recent commits (since the initial squash).

Comment: I don't fully follow what you did, but it seems like the merge brought the full history back, which makes sense if the branch your merged in has a full history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are working under at least one misconception, I think.

Let's break this down into these parts:

1. The command that shows history is `git log`.  It works by following the commit *graph*.  This graph is construct at the time you run `git log` based on information stored in each commit.  Most commits have a single *parent commit*, and `git log` shows you a commit, and then its parent, and then its parent's parent, and so on, making a nice orderly linear chain.<sup>1</sup>  A *merge* commit, however, has at least *two* parent commits, and `git log` shows you *both* of them, and both of their parents, and both of those parents' parents, and so on.<sup>2</sup>
2. The `git pull` command is merely `git fetch` followed by another command, usually `git merge`.
3. While `git merge` usually makes a merge commit, `git merge --squash` does not.  It's not just that it suppresses the commit itself (which it does), but substantially more important: the commit you get when *you* run `git commit` manually, which you must do to complete the squash "merge", is *not a merge commit*.  This is important in part because of item #1, but also because of item #4.
4. The way `git merge` figures out *what to merge* is to use the commit graph—the same graph as in item #1.  This relies fairly heavily<sup>3</sup> on having real, actual merges in the graph.

The normal (or at least more typical) way to use `git fetch` is with a *named remote* (or just "a remote" since a remote is just a name, and "named name" is kind of redundant).  It is possible to use a raw URL here though, which is how you are using `git fetch`.  When you use a raw URL, your `git fetch` must be followed immediately<sup>4</sup> by another command such as `git merge`, and of course that's what your `git pull` is doing for you.  (In fact, this is how `git pull` was originally designed to be used, before the Git community in general found out that naming remotes like `origin` is a whole lot better for most practical purposes.  This old way is, however, *why* `git pull` is such a complicated mess to explain and to use.)

In any case, as you have observed, merging two graphs results in `git log` following both graphs—which is working as designed; Git is *supposed* to do that.  You can tell `git log` not to do that, but the default is to follow both graphs.

Your first `pull` ran `git merge --squash`, which copied some work—that done since the merge base commit<sup>5</sup>—into your work-tree and made you manually commit that as a regular, non-merge commti.

Your second `pull`, without `--squash`, copied some work—specifically the work done since the merge base commit, almost certainly the same work already done<sup>6</sup>—into your work-tree and committed that as a true merge commit.

Any *subsequent* `pull` will copy only *new* work into your work-tree, now that your branch's history has been joined up with the other repository's history, via this `pull`-and-real-merge.  That part is what you want.  The fact that `git log` shows you the other history is the part you (apparently) don't want, but unless you use some other techniques,<sup>7</sup> you will be stuck with this: that is how Git is designed to be used.

(Note that a subsequent `--squash` merge or pull will set you up in this not-so-great "re-scan all the work" state, and gain little since any real merge has already joined up the histories in the way you wanted it not to.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Somewhat spoiling the nice neat chain, `git log` first figures out which commits to show, then *sorts them* by date stamp, then shows them.  This means that if the dates are messed up—accidentally or on purpose—what you see is not what happened.  To avoid this you can tell `git log` to use other sort orders; the easiest is to add `--graph`, which forces a topological sort *and* also draws a text-mode representation of the actual commit graph.

<sup>2</sup>If the histories rejoin—they do in most typical Git commit graphs—the log rejoins as well, i.e., you see only one copy of commits from this point backwards in time.  Git first selects all the commits to show, which could select any one commit many times due to history branching, and *then* shows them, which shows that one commit one time only.  (See also footnote 1.)

You can tell `git log` *not* to follow multiple histories: `git log --first-parent` follows only the "main" history.  You may want to use this method rather than trying to define fancier work flows.  If so, you probably *also* want to stick to a rebase work flow as much as possible, though.

<sup>3</sup>In particular, merges must find a *merge base*, and the merge base is the point at which the histories join up.  When you make a squash "merge", you mingle changes from one branch into another, but you do not join up their histories.  This means that a future `git merge` will have to merge those same changes *again*, unless you take some additional action (i.e., record a real merge commit).

<sup>4</sup>It does not have to be *that* immediate: `git fetch` writes what it did into `FETCH_HEAD`, which remains valid until the next `git fetch` overwrites it (and there's a flag to make a `git fetch` append instead of overwriting).  However, depending on just how you run `git fetch`, the information in `FETCH_HEAD` may be less useful, and in any case, the command to use for your next merge or rebase is a bit complicated as you may need to discard entries marked `not-for-merge`.  The `pull` command does all this for you, at the cost of making the merge or rebase occur immediately after the fetch, even though it would often be nice to *see* what came in.

<sup>5</sup>This assumes there is a merge-base commit.  If you "forked" your repository from the one you're now pulling from by URL (you probably should be using a remote instead of a URL), your history and theirs do join up at some point, and that is where the merge-base commit will be.  If the two repositories are completely unrelated, you're getting behavior that has been deemed overly dangerous, and is now disabled by default in Git version 2.9.

<sup>6</sup>Because of the way merge is defined, this winds up being a computationally-expensive way of doing nothing, if luck is with you.  (If not, it's still computationally-expensive but what it does is damage your code.)  The reason is that the merge action works by doing two diffs: `git diff $base HEAD`, to see what *you* have done, and `git diff $base $other`, to see what *they* have done.  (Here `$base` represents the merge base commit and `$other` represents the commit you are merging in to your branch.  As always, `HEAD` is your own current-branch-tip-commit.)  When you did that first squash merge, you got their work, so—assuming they have done nothing new, anyway—now "what you have done" *includes* "what they have done".  Hence, after a lot of work crunching through these two sets of diffs, Git decides that "what they have done" is already included in your `HEAD` commit, so it adds nothing new to your `HEAD`.

<sup>7</sup>Instead of the normal merge-into-mainline method, where you work on a side branch until it is ready, then merge it, you can reverse the merge flow.  You still make a side branch and work on it until it is ready, but then you squash-merge the side branch into the mainline (`master` or a release branch).  Then—this is the critical part—you do a *real* merge, not a squash merge, from the mainline back into the side branch, as soon as the side branch is to have any more work done on it.  This merge will form the merge base for the *next* merge action (whether this is a real merge, *or* a squash-"merge").

You must then leave these side branches around forever.<sup>8</sup>  This particular flow emulates what you might do in Mercurial.

<sup>8</sup>If you like, you can emulate a Mercurial "closed" branch by having a special reference or ref-name-space for "closed branch" or "closed branches", and rename the normal branch name into this name space.  You can also use dummy merges to tie such branches to each other, if for some reason you wanted to have just one external name keeping them alive.  Git has no tools for these operations but they are easy to build using Git's plumbing commands (you have to cheat to save reflogs, though).

Or, if you like, you can just (force) delete the side branch name entirely and lose the entire branch chain to the garbage collector.  Except for trivial side branches, though, this seems like a bad idea.